# Convert event from C# to VB.Net...how to?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events

I have to convert an C# code to VB.NET, but I've some problem....can you help me?

This is the C# source:

```
public static event ValueEnterEventHandler CallEvent;

public static void DispatchCompanyCall(string moduleName)
{
     if (IsReady && CallEvent != null)
           CallEvent(null, new ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, false));
}
```

I have tryed this:

```
Public Shared Event CallEvent As ValueEnterEventHandler

Public Shared Sub DispatchCompanyCall(moduleName As String)
    If IsReady AndAlso CallEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        CallEvent(Nothing, New ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, False))
    End If
End Sub
```

but I've this error message: CallEvent is an event and cannot called directly, use RaiseEvent statement to raise an event

What should I write? Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With VB.Net there is no need to check events for `null` / `Nothing` and you can just raise them directly via the `RaiseEvent` keyword

```
Public Shared Sub DispatchCompanyCall(moduleName As String)
    If IsReady Then
        RaiseEvent CallEvent(Nothing, New ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, False))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Eh... Do what the error message says and use `RaiseEvent`?!

```
Public Shared Event CallEvent As ValueEnterEventHandler

Public Shared Sub DispatchCompanyCall(moduleName As String)
    If IsReady AndAlso CallEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent CallEvent(Nothing, New ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, False))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, do what the error message says. See the RaiseEvent documentation for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what IDE you are using, but if you need to convert more code between C# and VB.NET or vice-versa you can use SharpDevelop (Menu Tools > Convert code to > C# | VB.NET (you also can to Python, Ruby and Boo)

For instance the code you wrote in C#:

```
public static event ValueEnterEventHandler CallEvent;

public static void DispatchCompanyCall(string moduleName)
{
    if (IsReady && CallEvent != null)
    CallEvent(null, new ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, false));
}
```

Is converted to VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Event CallEvent As ValueEnterEventHandler

Public Shared Sub DispatchCompanyCall(moduleName As String)
    If IsReady AndAlso CallEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent CallEvent(Nothing, New ValueEnterEventArgs(moduleName, False))
    End If
End Sub
```

Very useful.
Give it a try.