# How to implement C# multicast delegates in VB

Tags: events, delegates, raiseevent

Unfortunately the online free translators are unable to convert the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve;
```

I need the vb.net RaiseEvent equivalent syntax for this.
Many thanks

Comment: something like `AddHandler` or the like. I can't remember right now, it's been aeons since the last time I did any VB.Net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert event from C# to VB.Net...how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988957/convert-event-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net-how-to)

Comment: @user1937198: No, that is different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

### [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx)

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve
```

Comment: Thanks Robert Harvey - that's what I was looking for.